# How to ssh multiple hops without putting the local RSA key everywhere

Tags: linux, macos, ssh

I have a weird setup where I work from my mac, server A and server B. I can login to A directly without having password by adding my RSA keys, and login to B from A directly without using password too.

I sometimes wanted to login directly into server B from my mac, because B is where the production environment is running. I can use ssh with ProxyCommand, but then I have to add my keys into server B, is there any way I can avoid doing this? Because B is an auto managed server, the key is refreshed all the times.

Theoretically, since I can get from my mac to A (without password), and then from A to B (without password), I should be able to get into B directly. But I can't find the proper way of doing this without adding my key on mac into B's authorized_keys. Or is there a way I can automatically add my key during this login chain, because when I try to do that, ssh reports something about man-in-the-middle attack and rejects it.

Comment: How is it that you can ssh from A to B without password?

Comment: Btw, if all you are after is to skip having to type 2 ssh commands, you could run `ssh -t A ssh B`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `ProxyCommand` you don't need to put your key *anywhere*. All the authentications are initiated from your host, if you use the `-W` option like this:

```
ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p proxy
```

Comment: Oh wow, you're right. I haven't noticed this. What I was doing was like, I use ProxyCommand to log into server B, and forward server B's SSH port to my mac, and then when I try to log into the local port, password are asked. Is there any way around this? I was doing this because one of the tools I'm using doesn't support SSH with complicated commands, like ProxyCommand

Comment: You can also achieve the same using Port Forwarding. But it will take you to run more commands: First connect to jumphost and create local forward of target host to some port on your host and then connect to this new port. Something like this: `ssh -NTfL 2222:remote:22 proxy && ssh -p 2222 localhost` (untested)

Comment: You mean create a local forward on server A to forward the SSH port of server B, and then connect to this port on my mac?