# Shell Script - ssh to a private AWS EC2 instance through my NAT instance

Tags: linux, shell, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to create a shell script in order to allow a simple command line to connect to my EC2 instance under my private VPC.

The flow should be (I think) SSH tunnelling through my NAT instance into my private EC2 instance.

I tried to following command:

```
ssh -A -L 9000:ubuntu@my.private.instance.ip:22 ec2-user@my_nat_instance;
```

But all I get is a connection to my NAT instance..

What am I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Probably already answered here: https://superuser.com/questions/96489/ssh-tunnel-via-multiple-hops

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ssh multiple hops without putting the local RSA key everywhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33290407/how-to-ssh-multiple-hops-without-putting-the-local-rsa-key-everywhere)

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSH v7.3 onward supports a -J switch and a ProxyJump option, which allow one or more comma-separated jump hosts, so, you can simply do this now:

```
ssh -J jumpuser1@jumphost1,jumpuser2@jumphost2,...,jumpuserN@jumphostN user@host
```