# SSH: Run command through sub server

Tags: shell, unix, networking, ssh, server

My goal is to be able to send a command to an old server that can only be
reached by going through the new server.

I want to be able to automate this as much as possible.
I want to be able to just run a script and it will do the work for me so
that I don't have to type.

Meaning I would have to do the following:

```
ssh user@newserver
```

and then

```
ssh user@oldserver
```

Once I reach the old server I need to be able to run

```
curl icanhazip.com
```

and

```
cat /var/spool/cron/user
```

So far I was only able to do the following:

```
ssh -t -t root@newserver "ssh root@oldserver"
```

That would only allow me to reach the server, but I would have to manually send other commands.

I would Ideally want to be able to run something like this:

```
ssh -t -t root@newserver 'ssh root@oldserver "cat /var/spool/cron/user"'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ssh multiple hops without putting the local RSA key everywhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33290407/how-to-ssh-multiple-hops-without-putting-the-local-rsa-key-everywhere)

Comment: @Jakuje If I wanted to just login to server B then I would just have to do the following ssh -t -t root@serverA "ssh root@serverB"

Comment: No. It would allow you to run just `ssh serverB command`, without even knowing that you go throught `serverA`

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh -t -t root@newserver 'ssh root@oldserver "cat /var/spool/cron/user"'
```

This Actually worked. Not sure why it didn't before.