# Single line bash command/function for multihop scp without ProxyCommand

Tags: bash, scp

I have 3 machines `x` `y` `z`, among them `z` can access `x` only via `y` and `x` can access `z` only via `y`.

I want to write the following command in `~/.bashrc` of machine `y`.

For now I am doing SCP as below steps 1,2 and its working fine,

**To copy z to x**

1. First scp z to y from y

   ```
   scp root@192.0.44.4:/disk1/*.* ./
   ```
2. Then scp y to x from y

   ```
   sshpass -p root123 scp *.*  root@1.2.60.4:/aaa/bbb/
   ```

   What I want to do is I want to combine it to single line bash function,
   i.e, `z->y->x`

   ```
   scpzx() { scp root@192.0.44.4:/disk1/{"$1"} ./ ;sshpass -p root123 scp "$1" root@1.2.60.4:/aaa/bbb/ }
   ```

**To copy x to z**

1. scp x to y from y

   ```
   sshpass -p root123 scp root@1.2.60.4:/aaa/bbb/*.* ./
   ```
2. scp y to z from y

   ```
   scp ./*.* root@192.0.44.4:/disk1/
   ```

   What I want to do is I want to combine it to single line bash function, i.e., `x->y->z`

   ```
   scpxz() { sshpass -p root123 scp root@1.2.60.4:/aaa/bbb/{"$1"} ./ ;scp ./{"$1"} root@192.0.44.4:/disk1/ }
   ```

Where we pass `$1`=`file1,file2,file3` to `scpxz()` and `scpzx()`.
Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. `x` `y` `z` machines don't have `ProxyCommand` or `nc` aka `netcat`.

----[ Edited ] ----

I want to pass multiple files separated by , like `{file1,file2}` so that it can read it from `/disk1/` as `/disk1/file1` and `/disk1/file2` with single file it's working fine earlier as only if not provide curly braces `{ }` but I want it with the `{ }` so that I can pass multiple file name present in same parent directory /disk1 as curly brace will expand it under same parent directory like,  e.g. `scp /disk1/{file1,file2}` expand to `scp /disk1/file1 /disk1/file2`

Also I have tried ,

```
    scpzx() { for i in "$@"; scp root@192.0.44.4:/disk1/"$i" ./ ;sshpass -p root123 scp "$i" root@1.2.60.4:/aaa/bbb/ ;}
```

but I am getting error as `line 17: syntax error near unexpected token scp`

Comment: Are all these commands run from "Y"?  As in: Y does a GET from Z and then does a PUT to Z?

Comment: Only `Y` can copy and put to x and z i.e I am executing above mentioned all commands from  `Y`. Its like   "X<->Y<->Z" but  not possible direct `X<->Z`

Comment: I think there is a typo in the "copy z to x" part, as server x isn't mentioned in there - point 2 should be "scyp y to x from y", right?

Comment: [Corrected the typo] - Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ssh multiple hops without putting the local RSA key everywhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33290407/how-to-ssh-multiple-hops-without-putting-the-local-rsa-key-everywhere)

Comment: @Jakuje I think this is different as I just want to combine step 1 & 2. I don't want to do anything with RSA and all. Here I am getting bash error's for the single line and while passing multiple files.

Comment: @Jakuje Please let me know if any more edits I need to do here so that it won't feel duplicate of your mentioned question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**POST 1**

The function requires a slight change when not created in a script.  You must add a ";" before the last "}".  I would also remove the internal brackets as they're not really needed in this case.

For example:

```
scpzx() { scp root@192.0.44.4:/disk1/"$1" ./ ;sshpass -p root123 scp "$1" root@1.2.60.4:/aaa/bbb/ ;}
```

**POST 2**

If you are looking to cycle through the command line variables this will allow you to do that.  $@ references all command line variables passed to the function.

```
fTest() { for i in $@; do echo "$i"; done  ;}
```

For your script it would be something like:

```
scpxz() { for i in $@; do sshpass -p root123 scp root@1.2.60.4:/aaa/bbb/"$i" ./ ;scp ./"$i" root@192.0.44.4:/disk1/; done ;}
```

Comment: I want to pass multiple files separated by  `,` like {file1,file2} so that it can read it from /disk1/ as `/disk1/file1` and `/disk1/file2` with single file its working fine earlier as only  if not provide curly braces `{ }` but I want it with the `{ }` so that I can pass multiple file name present in same parent directory `/disk1` as curly brace will expand it under same parent directory.  e.g. scp `/disk1/{file1,file2}` expand to `scp /disk1/file1  /disk1/file2`

Comment: I tried for loop approach with your answer to access multiple files, I mentioned in edited question which giving me bash errors.
`

Comment: @ypp, I have updated my answer above to accommodate multiple files passed in as command line arguments.  Let me know how it does for you.

Comment: It worked only change I did is I combined both scp cmd's with &&. Thank you @jgshawkey

Comment: @ypp, no problem at all.  Good idea with the && to make sure the first one is successful before the second one kicks off.  Take care!

Answer (score 0):

You can try execute:

```
scp -3 x:path_to_file z:path_to_file
```

on `y` host. `-3` switch ensure  all transfer goes through local (in your case `y`) host.

Comment: `scp: illegal option -- 3`
`usage: scp [-1246BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]`
           `[-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]`
          ` [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2`

Comment: It was added to scp in 2010 or 2011, so you scp version is a little bit outdated

Comment: yes the scp seems outdated and I can't update the scp version as many others using those systems so I don't want to touch it. That why I am looking for more conventional basic way to achieve it.